# Update QProgressBar from within another class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm relatively new to Qt and GUI programming, and I'm kind of stumped.

I would like to update a `QProgressBar`'s progress such that the progress reflects actions taken in a class. The class is doing a lot of operations and I would like to be able to update the `QProgressBar` with the progress of these operations:

```
class Worker
{
...
public:
  void do_many_operations()
  {
    ...
    quint64 total_operations = ...;
    for (...)
    {
      /* do some operations */
      ...
      /* update the progress bar */
    }
  }
}
```

The part that I've got stuck at is how to, in as best an OO way as possible, update the `QProgressBar`.

One thought I had might be to make my `Worker` class a `QObject` and `emit` an update when necessary, or to pass the `QProgressBar` object to the `Worker` class's `do_many_operations()`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Updated to reflect that I meant `QProgressBar` not `QStatusBar`

Answer (score 0):

Most widgets do not draw any changes until Qt can process events.
You should be able to call the regular QStatusBar slot methods and then call the application's processEvents method.

```
void do_many_operations()
{
  /* Startup status bar */
  myStatusBar.showMessage("Beginning many operations.");
  QApplication::instance().processEvents();

  quint64 total_operations = ...;
  for (...)
  {
    /* do some operations */

    /* update the status bar (probably want a more dynamic message... */
    myStatusBar.showMessage("Doing work still");
    QApplication::instance().processEvents();
  }

  /* clear the status bar, no need to processEvents. */
  myStatusBar.clearMessage();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant a QProgressBar, not status bar. I updated my post. How do I access the ProgressBar on the form, though?

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `setValue(int)` will do, or if you have some signals, connect them with `setValue(int)`.

and of course, you have to `setMaximum()` before.

Comment: Ok, but the problem I am having is that the ProgressBar is a member of MainWindow and the Worker class is instantiated within a method of MainWindow. Should I pass the ProgressBar to the do_many_operations() function?